# Pointing subdomain (from cpanel, hosting company) to an external public IP

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system

How can I create a subdomain from a public IP and an existing domain name ?

I have a website hosted by an external hosting company.:

```
www.example.com
```

I have a public IP (not real): `127.180.150.20`

I have a LAN.

**What I want to do:**

I am developing a web application (php/html/perl) that will need a lot of space for that I have planed
  to have my own dedicated server. I want to use my own computer and assign it a public IP
  but the application should be accessed from the following subdomain address:

```
  www.app.example.com
```

- Is it possible to create a subdomain from the cpanel and point it to my public IP address?
- Do I need to set up maybe a DNS server and a client, what I predict will be tough

I don't necessarily need the step by step on how to achieve this but rather the outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a matter to define the correct A record for this name in the DNS zone file :

```
www.app.example.com    IN A 127.180.150.20
```

But this can only be done if you are the actual owner of `example.com` domain and can manage directly the DNS records. If this domain is owned by your hosting company, that you will need to ask them to do this change.

Answer (score 0):

If the server running cpanel also is the primary NS server for your domain, then yes, using these instructions: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/EditZone

Answer (score 0):

Is your public IP a fixed(static) or dynamic?.

Assuming it is a static one and your cPanel server is your primary dns server, you can simply add an "A" record to the zone file".

If you have WHM access, use the below link

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/EditZone

If you only have the cPanel access, follow the below link

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SimpleDnsEditor

Basically what you need to do is adding the following A record to the zone file

```
www.app.example.com.    IN A 127.180.150.20
```

If your public IP is dynamic and changing, the above methods will not work.